# doing_action() function stops my code from running

Tags: php, wordpress

My action is called by WP Cron so I'm trying to prevent it from running twice at the same time. So, I have the following function that uses [doing_action function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/doing_action/) to check if the action is running. Apparently, the code below can't run even when the action is not running. But when I removed the doing_action check, the code runs.

```
function upload_to_ipfs() {

    if ( !doing_action( 'upload_file' ) ) {
        //Code to run here
    }
}
add_action( 'upload_file', 'upload_to_ipfs' );
```

Comment: you can probably set a transient when the process starts and remove it when it's done and then check for the transient existence instead of the `doing_action`

Comment: _"Apparently, the code below can't run even when the action is not running."_ - if the action was _not_ currently running, then it would not _get_ to the point of executing this code in the first place. Checking if an action is running _from within the running action itself_ is a bit of a pointless thing to attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have a look at site transients.

```
<?php

function so_73821350_get_transient_name() {
    return 'so_73821350_transient_name'; // replace this with whatever you want
}

function so_73821350_upload_to_ipfs() {

    // get the existing transient
    //
    // If the transient does not exist, does not have a value, or has expired, 
    // then the return value will be false.
    $process_running = get_site_transient( so_73821350_get_transient_name() );

    if ( $process_running ) {
        // bail out in case the transient exists and has not expired
        // this means the process is still running
        return; 
    }

    // set the transient to flag the process as started
    // 60 is the time until expiration, in seconds
    set_site_transient( so_73821350_get_transient_name(), 1, 60);

    // Run the upload process here
    
    upload_function();

    // ...
    

    // delete the transient to remove the flag and allow the process to run again
    delete_site_transient( so_73821350_get_transient_name() ); 
    
}
add_action( 'upload_file', 'so_73821350_upload_to_ipfs' );
```

docs:

[get_site_transient()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_transient/)

[set_site_transient()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_site_transient/)

[delete_site_transient()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_site_transient/)

Comment: Thank you. But I'm confused with the line `if ( !$process_running )` cos I thought if the transient exists, we should get out. But isn't `if ( !$process_running )` means if $process_running is false? Anyway, when I used `if ( !$process_running )`, the function doesn't run at all regardless of how soon I triggered the cron.

Comment: check statement will be  `if ( $process_running )`

Comment: Yes. My bad. Initially I had the execution inside that if and then I replaced it with a return.

Answer (score -1):

You're running into a scenario where the code won't run because it's calling `!doing_action` on itself because the action IS running.

Also,

Wordpress `doing_action` works by looking at a global PHP variable is all.

This will not work since you're probably not on the same thread process (since a new one is started with every PHP request on most servers).

In which case you'll have to resort to an alternative method for checking.

One such alternative is checking the servers running processes for the action. Take a look at something like this https://write.corbpie.com/check-if-a-process-is-running-on-linux-with-php/ to help guide you in the right direction.

```
function is_server_doing_action(string $process): bool
{
    if (empty(trim(shell_exec("pgrep $process")))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function upload_to_ipfs() {

    if ( !is_server_doing_action( 'upload_file' ) ) {
        //Code to run here
    }
}
add_action( 'upload_file', 'upload_to_ipfs' );
```